# Bootstrap-tempus-dominus styling colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using  [bootstrap-tempus-dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/)  for Datetimepickers in my application.

How can I change the color of the displayed month and day's names with css

[image]

Comment: do you want to change highlighted text which is in red color box?

Comment: Yes the color is too bright (gray) I want to change it to black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the custom style below in your page it will work as desired:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.picker-switch{
    color:#000 !important;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th{
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

Check this example:

```js
$(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
```

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.picker-switch{
    color:#0f0 !important;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th{
  color:#0f0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```